# Using cross correlation in python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cross-correlation

I'm trying to solve a correlation problem where I need to find where a pattern sequence is found inside a signal sequence. At some point I was able to find the correct solution only to begin trying to optimize the code, and the code I had accomplished wasn't saved. Now the cross correlation function just won't solve correctly and I don't know why. I have restarted the kernel multiple times.

Here is the code and the links to the text files that contain the signal and the pattern.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBzHMUfmcx_gGR0arYPaQ5GB9MybXKRv/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TeSe9t8TeVHEp2BxKXYz6Ndlpah--yLg/view?usp=sharing

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

patron = np.loadtxt('patron.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
senal = np.loadtxt('señal.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
Fs=100
ts = np.arange(0,len(senal))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(ts,patron)
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(ts,senal)


corr = np.correlate(senal,patron,"same")
print(np.where(corr == np.amax(corr))) #this should be where correlation reaches its maximum value, and where the functions are most "similar"

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(ts,corr, 'r')
```

How do I know I had it right? I plotted the "senal" sequence shifted 799 places (the value I had when the code was right) with:

```
np.roll(senal,799)
plt.plot(senal)
```

which resulted in this graph. It looks pretty intuitive when it resulted in a maximum correlation at index 799:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello I fliped the 'patron' and 'senal' values in the correlate function function and it seems good:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

patron = np.loadtxt('patron.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
senal = np.loadtxt('señal.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
Fs=100
ts = np.arange(0,len(senal))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(ts,patron)
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(ts,senal)


corr = np.correlate(patron,senal,'same')
print(np.argmax(corr)) #this should be where correlation reaches its maximum value, and where the functions are most "similar"

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(corr, 'r')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for looking into it. You are right, by the numpy documentation of the correlation I should have placed the patron sequence as the second parameter of the np.correlate function. But I still don't understand how to extract the 799 displacement I had gotten before which looked too much of a coincidence to be wrong. The index I get from switching the sequences inside correlate and checking for its maximum still gets me to a strange index that I can't make sense of.

Comment: I dont know why you think that the 799 index was a good value, if you look at the signal axis at 799 point the signal dont look the same at all. In the example that I posted they are much closer. I dont know if there was another processing step that you were doing that would maybe calculate the lag and realign them even better?

Comment: Because that's what I got at some point, shifted the patron sequence by that amount and it looks identical. Also, I just got the solution to the problem and it is 800 (off by one position), only that I'm not being able to solve it by myself. There might be some theoretical issue that I am not understanding about correlation. And its not that at 799 the sequences look the same, its the shift of 799 places of patron that makes it look identical to senal, just how I showed on the last graph.

Comment: @GustavoHenriqueFossNeves yes i understand if you shift the signal by 799 you say it looks similar but if you actually look where 799 point is on the graph it is not where the signals align at all. Point 799 is far more left. But maybe you are shifting the signal differently and I dont know it, so ok if it works fine. Can you post the answer in case someon else has the same problem? I would like to see what is different as well.